# mysql min value column of floating numbers

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to find the min value of a column of floating numbers using a mysql function?  Suppose I have the following table:

> id | value 
>  a  | 24.88 
>  a  | 119.99

If I try:

`SELECT MIN(value) FROM [table name] GROUP BY id;`

mysql returns:
119.99

After testing this with different floating numbers I believe that this is the case because mysql takes the first character in each of the strings "1" and "2" and then selects a min based on which character is smaller.

I've read through this forum and others trying to find an answer but it seems nobody has raised this problem.

I should mention I've also tried CEIL(value) but that function also seems to have some bugs and I'd prefer to keep the number a floating number and not an integer.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the column is being stored as a character-based data type. You can solve this in one of two ways:

1. Change the column type to a numeric type
2. change the query to add CAST around the value: `MIN(CAST(value AS DECIMAL))`

The column change might look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table MODIFY COLUMN value double;
```

And, as far as I know, MySQL *will* attempt to convert the data for you. See [the note here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html#id981659), which states it "*tries*".

Comment: Thank you very much ctrahey.  You saved me so much time and I'm an idiot.  I had actually double-checked my column type before your suggestion, saw CHAR and figured that since it wasn't VARCHAR I'm alright.  I forgot that CHAR is not a numeric type.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Happy to help! And welcome to SO. It benefits the whole community (and specifically you and me) when you accept answers :-)